# Frameset do not work in rails 4.2

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title> ABC </title>
</head>

This is index.html.erb

<frameset rows="170,*" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
  <frame name="topNav" src="top_nav.html" />
</frameset>
</html>
```

My layout is false for this view. So, html, head is declared at this view only. Question is why does not this code work in erb files?

I see only "This is index.html.erb" message on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope everyone know that

```
framesets
```

should not come under/after body.

Problem with above code was line:

```
This is index.html.erb
```

Browser was converting taking this body tags. Removed this line from code and framesets started to appear.